# How to addClass and removeClass with different element on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple dom that I would like to achieve:

```
<header>
    <button class="open-btn></button>
</header>

<nav class="active">
    <button class="close-btn"></button>
</nav>
```

How do I achieve the simple addClass and removeClass function on Angular with separate element?

I've read up on Service, Factory, and Controller, it sounds quite confusing to me.

I've able to successfully used Controller to do add and remove class on the same controller, let's say `open-btn` and `close-btn` both under `nav`, but how about if I am using different element? What I've done seems quite wrong to me, is it the right way? Do I have to register it to Service/Factory instead?

**Scenario**:

When the user click on `open-btn`, the element `nav` will have a class of `active`, if the user click on `close-btn`, then `nav` will remove it's `active` button.

This seems so easy with jQuery, but how would I do it with Angular way?

Comment: What does relate to class should come up with [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the buttons set a value in the scope, and then give the elements classes based on the value of that element using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<header>
   <button class="open-btn" ng-click="isActive = true">Open</button>
</header>

<nav ng-class="{ 'active': isActive }">
   <button class="close-btn" ng-click="isActive = false">Close</button>
</nav>
```

From the `ng-class` documentation:

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair
>   of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a
>   class name.

Comment: Hey Danny, this looks great, but I do have to add it to a single controller, correct?

Comment: Mmmmm...yes. I see you added in a comment that they do not have the same controller, but I think I would need to see more of your code to know how to handle the situation.  It's not clear to me how the two controllers would be interacting. At first glance they look like two buttons on a single page (with me assuming a single controller).

Comment: You are right, they both on the same page. I am having some confusion with organising controllers and when to use it, on this situation, I thought I should create a HeaderController and NavController, lol.

Comment: If you're explicitly doing it for a particular reason, then it is very likely overkill. The page or directive could quite possibly have a single controller that handles both buttons.

Comment: great! thank you very much and that clears my mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular has **[`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)** to add/remove class

Like this

ctrl

```
$scope.isOpen=false;

$scope.open=function(){
  $scope.isOpen=true;
}
$scope.close=function(){
  $scope.isOpen=false;
}
```

Html

```
<header>
    <button class="open-btn" ng-click="open()"></button>
</header>

<nav class="active" ng-class="{'active': isOpen }">
    <button class="close-btn" ng-click="close()"></button>
</nav>
```

Comment: It has to be within it's context  . Like there is only one controller then it has be same controller if there is nested controller then it has to be at least it self or it's parent . @draftdraft88

Comment: Thanks Anik, I'd prefer your way of using function.